# Restoring a VirtualBox VM to a clean/default state?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, iso-image

I am playing around with Virtual Box and installed an Ubuntu 12.04 ISO on a my first VM. Now I want to "wipe" that VM clean and undo all the software I had installed on it. My co-worker said the easiest thing to do is to just re-install Ubuntu and overwrite everything.

What's the easiest way to do this with VBox? Should I just delete the whole VM and recreate it from scratch? It would be nice if I can just tell VBox "hey, take this VM, erase everything on it, and then replace it with this ISO" instead of having to delete the entire VM and create a new one. Is this possible? If so, how? If not, what's my best remedy here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to want to preserve the configurations for the virtual machine.

The easy way to accomplish this is obvious: detach the virtual disk image and replace it with a new one.

The configurations for the virtual machine remain in tact, but the stored data is gone.

#### 1. In Settings >> Storage, remove the current virtual disk image.

[image]

#### 2. Add a new attachment: "Add Hard Disk".

[image]
[image]

#### 3. "Create new disk"

[image]

#### 4. VirtualBox will use the new disk.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Deltik (+1) - I presume I accomplish this in Settings >> Storage? I see an "Attributes" section with a CD icon that allows me to choose an ISO? Do I just choose the same ISO as before (would doing so cause VBox to overwrite my old VM with the new ISO)?

Comment: @zharvey You replace the `.vdi` file with a new one.  (Sorry for the late clarification, but I'm on a different computer right now, so I just downloaded VirtualBox to get screenshots.)

Comment: Thanks again - I removed my existing attachment and added a new one (pointing to my Ubuntu ISO). I restarted the VM and got the following error: `FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium. System halted.` Where am I going wrong here? Thanks again!

Comment: Create a new **hard disk**.  Don't point it to the ISO file.  Then start up the virtual machine.  You'll still get the fatal error, but go to `Devices >> CD/DVD Devices >> Choose a virtual CD/DVD disk file...`, choose your ISO file, then reset the virtual machine.  [(Screenshot)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wrUPW.png)

Answer (score 9):

For future reference, after you've installed the virtual machine and have everything running, create a **snapshot**. This will allow you to revert back to this squeaky, clean state whenever you want!

[image: snapshot]

---

**See Also:**

- [VirtualBox - Chapter 1: Snapshots](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#snapshots)